# Blue line is not activated on Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, editor

I don't see the blue edit line on my Xcode. I also activated it on the settings. Can someone kindly tell me how to make this work?

Comment: Update your question with the following information: what you mean by the blue edit line, what you did to activate it in the settings, what you expect to see, and what you are seeing. Also update with the version of Xcode you are using. Supplying this updated information will increase your chances of someone being able to answer your question.

Comment: @MarkSzymczyk I am using the latest version of Xcode 11.3.1, the blue edit line is the sidebar that appears when you edit the code. I activated it from the settings on "Source Control" but the problem is that you can't see it and besides the bar that must be there is only the space!

Comment: Is your project under source control? The project must be under source control for the blue bar to appear. You can tell if your project is under source control if you add some text and save. The file will have an M next to it in the left side of the project window.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Can you elaborate? Where do I enter the text and save it?

Comment: Open a source code file. Add some code or add a code comment. Save the file by pressing Cmd-S.

Answer (score 1):

The "blue line" referred to in the question is part of a new feature Apple added to its version control support in Xcode 11. When you make changes to a file that is under version control, a blue bar appears on the left edge of Xcode's editor.

[image: Blue Bar]

Clicking the blue bar lets you quickly discard changes you make to files.

In order for the blue bar to appear, your Xcode project must be under version control. When you create a new Xcode project, there is a checkbox to create a git repository and place the project under version control. If you have an existing project you want to place under version control, choose Source Control > Create Git Repositories in Xcode.

Comment: Thanks now I understand, so the bar only appears when you create a git repository.

Comment: Hello Mark, have you experienced the blue bar disappearance issue after reinstalling macOS and migrating data via Migration Assistant? All my projects have source control enabled, and I can confirm that “Show Source Control changes“ is also checked in the Xcode preferences, but the blue bar is just never appear. If I restart into my old version of macOS and run the same version of Xcode, the blue bar is right there. I tried many stuff like updating Git, moving Xcode into the new Applications folder etc. but still couldn’t get it to work.

Comment: Turns out if an Xcode project is inside another volume, which different from the volume macOS is currently running on, there will have no blue bar for Source Control.

Comment: @Jonny I have not experienced the blue bar disappearing.

Comment: In my case it's even weirder. 
I've recently migrated to a new Mac. 
The blue bar still works for all the files in the project I'm working on, except for a single one.
Said file is under Git tracking, Xcode detects changes in all other places, etc.